# Find out if an HTTPS url is online

Tags: java, android, ssl

I need a function which returns true if the certificate of a secure website is signed by a CA. In Android, if you try to connect to a self-signed certificate, it throws an SSLException, in this case I just catch it and return false. You can check the code:

```
public static boolean isValidCertificate(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpsURLConnection con;
    try {
        con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.connect();
        con.disconnect();
        return true;
    } catch (SSLException e) {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

My problem is that I want the function to throw an Exception if the site is not avaliable. But I just found out that Android throws the same SSLException in this case, with the same message: "No trusted server certificate".

Is there any way of knowing whether the server is online regardless of whether the certificate is valid or not?

Thanks!

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219208/is-it-possible-to-get-java-to-ignore-the-trust-store-and-just-accept-whatever)

Comment: npe, I'm sorry but I am not asking how to avoid the CA check. Indeed, I already know how to do that.

Comment: Then perhaps post full stack trace of the exception you're getting. And the code you use to trust all certificates.

Comment: My code is all right, but I did a mistake, thank you because I've been thinking about your last post and I found the solution. I'll post it.

Comment: ' if the site is not available ... Android throws the same SSLException in this case, with the same message: "No trusted server certificate".' I find this impossible to believe. It will throw a `ConnectException`, `NoRouteToHostException`, `UnknownHostException`, etc. You must be doing something very strange.

Comment: Well, that was what I thought but you can see the code. And I swear you that when I had an url = https://10.0.2.2/fakeurl It threw an SSLException. I didn't understand how on earth could throw that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just need to check if the URL is online before calling this function. I can use my httpsclient without CA signed check and get the response, then, I call this method.

Comment: So in other words you were ignoring the `ConnectException` and proceeding with the certificate verification anyway.

Comment: I didn't ignore `ConnectException` because I didn't get it!

Answer (score 2):

Test it with a fake URL such as "https://flimflam.asdfasdfasdfg.com" and see what happens in your case.

If should fire off an `IOException` if no connection was made based on the `openConnection` method. Most likely this is more of a timeout and you'll spend time waiting for the timeout period.

Comment: I tried with a fake URL and debug the function, it throws the same exception. That annoys me...

Answer (score 1):

try using `con.getResponseCode();` before `con.disconnect();` to get exception that you want.

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. But thanks! (It threw the same exception).