# How to resolve error of certificate while accessing vcenter using java?

Tags: java, ssl, vmware

I am using vmware API. By using this API I am able to get information of ESX devices. Now I want to get information about vcenter using this API, but get exception "Java.rmi.remoteException: VI SDK Invoke exception : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandShakeException: java.security."

Here is a code:

```
public void realesx(){
System.out.println("Running ESX Realtime for host ..."+host);
JSONObject esxcmdout = new JSONObject();
String url = "https://" + host + "/sdk/vimService";
try {
ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(new URL(url), user, pass,true);
System.out.println("host :"+host+"---"+si.getAboutInfo().getFullName());

System.out.println(" Version is .. " +si.getAboutInfo().version);
System.out.println(" os type is .. " +si.getAboutInfo().osType);
System.out.println("Vendor is .. " + si.getAboutInfo().vendor);
System.out.println("name is" + si.getAboutInfo().name);
try{
esxcmdout.put("vmWayerVersion", si.getAboutInfo().version);
esxcmdout.put("vmWayerOSType", si.getAboutInfo().osType);
esxcmdout.put("vmWayerVendor", si.getAboutInfo().vendor);
esxcmdout.put("vmWayerName", si.getpublic void realesx(){
System.out.println("Running ESX Realtime for host ..."+host);
JSONObject esxcmdout = new JSONObject();
String url = "https://" + host + "/sdk/vimService";
try {
ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(new URL(url), user, pass,true);
System.out.println("host :"+host+"---"+si.getAboutInfo().getFullName());

System.out.println(" Version is .. " +si.getAboutInfo().version);
System.out.println(" os type is .. " +si.getAboutInfo().osType);
System.out.println("Vendor is .. " + si.getAboutInfo().vendor);
System.out.println("name is" + si.getAboutInfo().name);
try{
esxcmdout.put("vmWayerVersion", si.getAboutInfo().version);
esxcmdout.put("vmWayerOSType", si.getAboutInfo().osType);
esxcmdout.put("vmWayerVendor", si.getAboutInfo().vendor);
esxcmdout.put("vmWayerName", si.getAboutInfo().name);
}
catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

ManagedEntity[] managedEntities = new InventoryNavigator(
si.getRootFolder()).searchManagedEntities("VirtualMachine");
ManagedEntity[] hostmanagedEntities = new InventoryNavigator(
        si.getRootFolder()).searchManagedEntities("HostSystem");

for (ManagedEntity hostmanagedEntity : hostmanagedEntities) {
HostSystem hostsys = (HostSystem) hostmanagedEntity;
String ESXhostname = hostsys.getName();
//System.out.println("main system version is .. " + hostsys.getConfig());
HostListSummary hls = hostsys.getSummary();
    HostHardwareSummary hosthwi = hls.getHardware();
    HostListSummaryQuickStats hqs = hls.getQuickStats();
    Datastore[] HDS = hostsys.getDatastores();
    StringBuilder DS = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0;i <HDS.length;i++){
      DatastoreSummary dsm =HDS[i].getSummary();

       DS.append(dsm.name+":"+dsm.capacity+":"+dsm.freeSpace+"-");
       }

int MEM=hqs.overallMemoryUsage;
int UPT=hqs.getUptime();
Integer CPU=hqs.getOverallCpuUsage();   

String esxkey = "ESXRealInfo";
String esxvalue = "ESXhostname-" + ESXhostname
    + ";CPU Usage-" + CPU + ";MEM Usage-"
    + MEM + ";UPTIME-" + UPT+"; Datastores -"+DS;
try {
esxcmdout.put(esxkey, esxvalue);
} catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

for (int i = 0; i < managedEntities.length; i++) {
    VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine) managedEntities[i];
    String vmName = vm.getName();

    String vmIP = vm.getGuest().getIpAddress();
    VirtualMachineConfigInfo config = vm.getConfig();
    VirtualHardware hw = config.getHardware();
    String vmVersion = config.version;
    System.out.println("######### vm version is  ###### ...  "+ vmVersion);
    int vmCPU = hw.getNumCPU();
    int vmMem = hw.getMemoryMB();
    String vmkey = "vm" + i;
        String vmvalues = "Name-" + vmName + ";IP-" + vmIP + ";vmCPU-"
            + vmCPU + ";vmMem-" + vmMem + ";vmVersion-" + vmVersion;
           System.out.println("string to write is... "+vmvalues);
    try {
        esxcmdout.put(vmkey, vmvalues);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
    si.getServerConnection().logout();
    }

    catch (InvalidProperty e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeFault e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        runMT.httpput(runtype, host, vmwtype, esxcmdout);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}AboutInfo().name);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    ManagedEntity[] managedEntities = new InventoryNavigator(
                si.getRootFolder()).searchManagedEntities("VirtualMachine");
    ManagedEntity[] hostmanagedEntities = new InventoryNavigator(
                si.getRootFolder()).searchManagedEntities("HostSystem");

    for (ManagedEntity hostmanagedEntity : hostmanagedEntities) {
    HostSystem hostsys = (HostSystem) hostmanagedEntity;

    String ESXhostname = hostsys.getName();
    //System.out.println("main system version is .. " + hostsys.getConfig());

    HostListSummary hls = hostsys.getSummary();
            HostHardwareSummary hosthwi = hls.getHardware();
            HostListSummaryQuickStats hqs = hls.getQuickStats();
            Datastore[] HDS = hostsys.getDatastores();
            StringBuilder DS = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i=0;i <HDS.length;i++){
                DatastoreSummary dsm =HDS[i].getSummary();

                DS.append(dsm.name+":"+dsm.capacity+":"+dsm.freeSpace+"-");
            }

    int MEM=hqs.overallMemoryUsage;
    int UPT=hqs.getUptime();
    Integer CPU=hqs.getOverallCpuUsage();   

    String esxkey = "ESXRealInfo";
    String esxvalue = "ESXhostname-" + ESXhostname
            + ";CPU Usage-" + CPU + ";MEM Usage-"
            + MEM + ";UPTIME-" + UPT+"; Datastores -"+DS;
    try {
        esxcmdout.put(esxkey, esxvalue);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < managedEntities.length; i++) {
    VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine) managedEntities[i];
    String vmName = vm.getName();
    String vmIP = vm.getGuest().getIpAddress();
    VirtualMachineConfigInfo config = vm.getConfig();
    VirtualHardware hw = config.getHardware();
    String vmVersion = config.version;
    System.out.println("######### vm version is  ###### ...  "+ vmVersion);
    int vmCPU = hw.getNumCPU();
    int vmMem = hw.getMemoryMB();
    //sasSystem.out.println(vmName + vmIP + vmCPU + vmMem);
    String vmkey = "vm" + i;
    String vmvalues = "Name-" + vmName + ";IP-" + vmIP + ";vmCPU-"
            + vmCPU + ";vmMem-" + vmMem + ";vmVersion-" + vmVersion;
            System.out.println("string to write is... "+vmvalues);
    try {
        esxcmdout.put(vmkey, vmvalues);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    si.getServerConnection().logout();
    }

    catch (InvalidProperty e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeFault e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        runMT.httpput(runtype, host, vmwtype, esxcmdout);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code works fine for collecting information of ESX devices. 
How do I resolve error of certificate for vcenter?
Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: [Is it possible to get Java to ignore the “trust store” and just accept whatever SSL certificate it gets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219208/is-it-possible-to-get-java-to-ignore-the-trust-store-and-just-accept-whatever)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the certificate so go through this [vSphere_Documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vco_install_config.doc_42/GUID39C552FA-0225-4D29-A4AC-7680252A5EC8.html) page to know import certificates.

edit:

try the given below code and have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889058/programmatically-import-ca-trust-cert-into-existing-keystore-file-without-using)

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
String fileName = "D:\\certs_path\\cacerts"; // cerrtification file path
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", fileName);
```

Comment: How to do it programmatically? Can I import certificate using java program?

Answer (score 0):

try changing the last argument on the ServiceInstance to `false` like this: `ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(new URL(url), user, pass,false);`