# JavaFx Webview JDK 8 can not load self signed certificate

Tags: java, ssl, webview, javafx, java-8

I tried to implement webview into my javafx app and I'm using JDK 8 to develop it.

When I use webEngine to load any HTTPS certificate website it works fine:

```
webEngine.load("https://google.com");
```

But if I use my HTTPS self-signed certificate  it can't open it. I tried to use this code to show you the problem:

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
      new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
      public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {                               
             if (webEngine.getLoadWorker().getException() != null && newState == State.FAILED){
            System.out.println(webEngine.getLoadWorker().getException().toString());
        }
  }
});
```

And my problem is:

> java.lang.Throwable: SSL handshake failed

I tried to add the following code to trust all hosts before use my webview, but it doesn't work:

```
// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
    new X509TrustManager() {     
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
            return null;
        } 
        public void checkClientTrusted( 
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            } 
        public void checkServerTrusted( 
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    } 
}; 

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); 
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom()); 
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
} 

webEngine.load("https://example.com");
```

Is anyway to fix it?

**Update**

I add -Djavax.net.debug=all to VMOption to view details of this error, then I find:

> URL-Loader-11, received EOFException: error
>   URL-Loader-11, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Following is full log:

```
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
URL-Loader-11, setSoTimeout(3600000) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1429261936 bytes = { 78, 102, 51, 3, 227, 71, 247, 110, 13, 31, 1, 249, 251, 191, 182, 146, 152, 35, 185, 132, 144, 219, 68, 50, 42, 165, 168, 205 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 207
0000: 01 00 00 CB 03 03 55 31   CE 70 4E 66 33 03 E3 47  ......U1.pNf3..G
0010: F7 6E 0D 1F 01 F9 FB BF   B6 92 98 23 B9 84 90 DB  .n.........#....
0020: 44 32 2A A5 A8 CD 00 00   46 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C C0  D2*.....F.#.'.<.
0030: 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  %.).g.@...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 07 C0   11 00 05 C0 02 C0 0C C0  ..3.2...........
0050: 2B C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0  +./...-.1.......
0060: 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00   16 00 13 00 04 00 FF 01  ................
0070: 00 00 5C 00 0A 00 34 00   32 00 17 00 01 00 03 00  ..\...4.2.......
0080: 13 00 15 00 06 00 07 00   09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B 00  ................
0090: 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E 00   0F 00 10 00 11 00 02 00  ................
00A0: 12 00 04 00 05 00 14 00   08 00 16 00 0B 00 02 01  ................
00B0: 00 00 0D 00 1A 00 18 06   03 06 01 05 03 05 01 04  ................
00C0: 03 04 01 03 03 03 01 02   03 02 01 02 02 01 01     ...............
URL-Loader-11, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 207
[Raw write]: length = 212
0000: 16 03 03 00 CF 01 00 00   CB 03 03 55 31 CE 70 4E  ...........U1.pN
0010: 66 33 03 E3 47 F7 6E 0D   1F 01 F9 FB BF B6 92 98  f3..G.n.........
0020: 23 B9 84 90 DB 44 32 2A   A5 A8 CD 00 00 46 C0 23  #....D2*.....F.#
0030: C0 27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29   00 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13  .'.<.%.).g.@....
0040: 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33   00 32 C0 07 C0 11 00 05  ./.....3.2......
0050: C0 02 C0 0C C0 2B C0 2F   00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E  .....+./...-.1..
0060: 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A   C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13  ................
0070: 00 04 00 FF 01 00 00 5C   00 0A 00 34 00 32 00 17  .......\...4.2..
0080: 00 01 00 03 00 13 00 15   00 06 00 07 00 09 00 0A  ................
0090: 00 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19   00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10  ................
00A0: 00 11 00 02 00 12 00 04   00 05 00 14 00 08 00 16  ................
00B0: 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D   00 1A 00 18 06 03 06 01  ................
00C0: 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01   03 03 03 01 02 03 02 01  ................
00D0: 02 02 01 01                                        ....
URL-Loader-11, received EOFException: error
URL-Loader-11, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
URL-Loader-11, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
URL-Loader-11, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
URL-Loader-11, called closeSocket()
URL-Loader-11, called close()
URL-Loader-11, called closeInternal(true)
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1429261936 bytes = { 9, 49, 116, 72, 24, 164, 72, 165, 44, 25, 150, 147, 0, 29, 236, 63, 194, 176, 136, 220, 66, 244, 111, 254, 15, 109, 124, 206 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 207
0000: 01 00 00 CB 03 03 55 31   CE 70 09 31 74 48 18 A4  ......U1.p.1tH..
0010: 48 A5 2C 19 96 93 00 1D   EC 3F C2 B0 88 DC 42 F4  H.,......?....B.
0020: 6F FE 0F 6D 7C CE 00 00   46 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C C0  o..m....F.#.'.<.
0030: 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  %.).g.@...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 07 C0   11 00 05 C0 02 C0 0C C0  ..3.2...........
0050: 2B C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0  +./...-.1.......
0060: 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00   16 00 13 00 04 00 FF 01  ................
0070: 00 00 5C 00 0A 00 34 00   32 00 17 00 01 00 03 00  ..\...4.2.......
0080: 13 00 15 00 06 00 07 00   09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B 00  ................
0090: 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E 00   0F 00 10 00 11 00 02 00  ................
00A0: 12 00 04 00 05 00 14 00   08 00 16 00 0B 00 02 01  ................
00B0: 00 00 0D 00 1A 00 18 06   03 06 01 05 03 05 01 04  ................
00C0: 03 04 01 03 03 03 01 02   03 02 01 02 02 01 01     ...............
URL-Loader-11, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 207
[Raw write]: length = 212
0000: 16 03 03 00 CF 01 00 00   CB 03 03 55 31 CE 70 09  ...........U1.p.
0010: 31 74 48 18 A4 48 A5 2C   19 96 93 00 1D EC 3F C2  1tH..H.,......?.
0020: B0 88 DC 42 F4 6F FE 0F   6D 7C CE 00 00 46 C0 23  ...B.o..m....F.#
0030: C0 27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29   00 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13  .'.<.%.).g.@....
0040: 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33   00 32 C0 07 C0 11 00 05  ./.....3.2......
0050: C0 02 C0 0C C0 2B C0 2F   00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E  .....+./...-.1..
0060: 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A   C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13  ................
0070: 00 04 00 FF 01 00 00 5C   00 0A 00 34 00 32 00 17  .......\...4.2..
0080: 00 01 00 03 00 13 00 15   00 06 00 07 00 09 00 0A  ................
0090: 00 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19   00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10  ................
00A0: 00 11 00 02 00 12 00 04   00 05 00 14 00 08 00 16  ................
00B0: 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D   00 1A 00 18 06 03 06 01  ................
00C0: 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01   03 03 03 01 02 03 02 01  ................
00D0: 02 02 01 01                                        ....
URL-Loader-11, received EOFException: error
URL-Loader-11, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
URL-Loader-11, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
URL-Loader-11, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
URL-Loader-11, called closeSocket()
webEngine result FAILED
java.lang.Throwable: SSL handshake failed
java.lang.Throwable: SSL handshake failed
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.describeError(WebEngine.java:1390)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1329)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$1100(WebEngine.java:1207)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1194)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2373)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2217)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFail(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.notifyDidFail(URLLoader.java:842)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.access$1300(URLLoader.java:43)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader$7.run(URLLoader.java:824)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I have written a browser using the JavaFX WebView control. Everything is fine until I try to load an encrypted page. I try https://www.gmail.com and I get an "Unknown Error" in the exception property of the load worker. This only happens when I package the application as a stand-alone; when I run the project in NetBeans everything is fine. I am guessing it has to do with SSL certificates, but I tried pretty much everything I could think of, including importing each certificate in the trust store with "keytool," but nothing works.

Any ideas? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than trying to implement your own trust manager can you [import the self-signed certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail) to be trusted into your existing jre cacerts truststore before you run your program?

Comment: I also tried add my certificate to jre cacerts: 
keytool -import -alias pop3 -keystore "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\lib\
security\cacerts" -file pop3.cer. 
Then i got:
Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore.
But nothing change. It still throw "SSL handshake failed"

Comment: By "standalone" I am guessing you mean an app bundled with javapackager. If so, does the same JVM get bundled that the keytool inserts your certificate into?

Comment: The problem in your log *can't* be a certificate error, you are getting "EOF" (FIN) before the server even sends its cert. I assume "my HTTPS self-signed cert" means your own *server using* that cert (and key); is that server on the same machine or different? Does it log or display anything when the error occurs? Is "stand-alone" on the same machine as NetBeans? Could there be a firewall or proxy or somesuch in the failing path(s) but not the successful one(s)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ran into the same problem as you. Guess it is because JDK 8 uses TLS1.2 as default (https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls). Forcing the client to use TLS 1 solved this problem for me.

Try using -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1".

Answer (score 4):

In your solution with TrustManager, you need to add additional statements after installing the all-trusting trust manager.

I found the full solution here:

http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/

I tested it on JDK-9.0.1 and it works.

```
// Create all-trusting host name verifier
HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
};

// Install the all-trusting host verifier
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I added the following static block(USING JAVA 8)

```
    static {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            }
        } };
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        }
        catch (KeyManagementException | java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }

        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    }
```

With the following imports

```
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
```