# JavaFX WebView can't load certain sites

Tags: java, webview, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I'm trying to use JavaFX's WebView to load this [site](https://news.ycombinator.com/news), but all I get is a blank screen. The WebView is working perfectly fine on other sites; it gets 100/100 on ACID3 and loads other HTTPS sites without any problems whatsoever.

I can't find anything particularly wrong with the site either. It has a proper, non-expired certificate signed by proper CA, and SSL Labs report [a B grade](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=news.ycombinator.com). I tried all the major browsers on it and none report any certificate or SSL related issues; the site renders fine on all of them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even a simple "yeah the site's broken for me too" or "no problems here" would help a lot.

I'm using Java SDK 1.8.0_45-b14 on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reason is `java.lang.Throwable: SSL handshake failed`

One solution can be: from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5671038/1032167:

```
     TrustManager trm = new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {return null;}
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
    };

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trm }, null);
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```

There is also post, probably about similar case: [JavaFx Webview JDK 8 can not load self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655977/javafx-webview-jdk-8-can-not-load-self-signed-certificate)

How do i know that it was `SSL handshake failed`

```
webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue ov, 
                      Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
            System.out.println(webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty());
             ...
```

also adding add `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to VMOption shows

> URL-Loader-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>
> unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: While there is useful debugging info in this answer (which was extremely helpful debugging this problem on JavaFX 17/JDK17), the "solution" is *terrible*.
It **disables certificate validation for all connections in the entire JVM**, *highly unsafe*.

For a more-targetted approach, see [How can I use different certificates on specific connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-can-i-use-different-certificates-on-specific-connections/859271#859271)