# Convincing java to talk to "localstack" via SSL

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Am hoping to use [localstack](https://libraries.io/github/localstack/localstack) to simulate elasticsearch/kinesis/dynamo. Am running into troubles with my elastic code wanting HTTPS endpoints.

Testing via java 11/IntelliJ

In all cases am hitting this error:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
 certification path to requested target
```

I've tried:

- Starting localstack with the USE_SSL environment variable set. curl commands (EG "curl -k https://localhost:port") for elastic work but java does not.
- Using localstack annotations ("@RunWith(LocalstackDockerTestRunner.class)" and passing in "USE_SSL" as a param - no go
- Telling Java to ignore "bad" certs via `System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.DISABLE_CERT_CHECKING_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");` - no go
- Passing cmdline param `-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking` - no go

I feel like what Im looking for is doable.. just can't seem to find the right combination of settings.

Comment: Have you tried looking into [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219208/is-it-possible-to-get-java-to-ignore-the-trust-store-and-just-accept-whatever)?

Comment: Just did. Nothing different - same error(s). I feel like AWS is ignoring all the "trust everything" messages;

Comment: How are you accessing Elasticsearch? Using some ready made library? Using java's original HTTPSURLConnection? Using Apache HTTPClient?  Using Java11 new HttpClient?

Comment: Using the RestHighLevelClient - which is injected

Comment: How did you run your java application from cmdline? `java -Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking -jar my.jar` or `java -jar my.jar -Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking`?
The first version should work. The position where you place this, makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the `RestHighLevelClient` yourself (or control the creation of this object), you can use the constructor that accepts a `RestClientBuilder`.

Use `RestClient.builder()` method to create a `RestClientBuilder` with a custom `SSLContext`. The following is from [Elasticsearch source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/client/documentation/RestClientDocumentation.java#L389):

```
        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "https"))
            .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                @Override
                public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(
                        HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                    return httpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(sslContext);
                }
            });
```

In your case you need to create an SSLContext that trusts all hosts:

```java
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
context.init(null, new TrustManager[] {
  new X509TrustManager {
    void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
    void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
    void getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
  }
}, null);
```

The above is completely untested but may get you started. Feel free to update this answer with more details if it works for you.